# Props from contextual provider: Property 'xxx' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & InterfaceProps'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am getting a Typescript error of `Property 'toggleAuthError' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & InterfaceProps'.ts(2322)` when trying to pass a function from a context provider to a component.

The context provider is

```
interface InterfaceProps {
  children?: any;
}

interface InterfaceState {
  error: any;
  toggleAuthError: any;
}

const GlobalContext = createContext({
  error: null,
  toggleAuthError: () => {}
});

export class GlobalProvider extends React.Component<InterfaceProps, InterfaceState> {
  public toggleAuthError = ({ authError }: any) => {
    this.setState({ error: authError });
  };

  public state = {
    error: null,
    toggleAuthError: this.toggleAuthError
  };

  public render() {
    console.log(this.state);
    const { children } = this.props;
    return <GlobalContext.Provider value={this.state as any}>{children}</GlobalContext.Provider>;
  }
}

export const GlobalConsumer = GlobalContext.Consumer;
```

And the component in which I am accessing the value is

```
const SignInPageBase = () => (
  <GlobalProvider>
    {({ toggleAuthError }: any) => (
      <Form toggleAuthError={toggleAuthError} />
    )}
  </GlobalProvider>   
);
```

The error is shown on the `import` component `Form`.

What is causing this error and how can I fix it? I have many components that are similar without this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to haved missed out your `GlobalConsumer` to consume the context (see [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#contextconsumer)).

```
const SignInPageBase = () => (
  <GlobalProvider>
    <GlobalConsumer>
  {({ toggleAuthError }: any) => (
      <Form toggleAuthError={toggleAuthError} />
    )}
</GlobalConsumer>
  </GlobalProvider>   
);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Form` is a standard HTML tag (as opposite to react component).
You're getting this error because `toggleAuthError` is not a standard attribute for `Form` tag.

One good solution would be to stick to the standard and use custom `props` only for your react component, Which in this case may be to wrapper the `Form` with your own component and use the `toggleAuthError` attribute on it.

Sometimes it is not possible or simply not maintainable (Like when you use external libraries which demand using such attribute on the element directly), So another option would be to expand the type-definition to include the additions you like.

For doing so, create a type-definition file (like `my-app.d.ts`), then you can add the definition you like as you do normally with typescript:

```
declare module 'react' {
  interface HTMLAttributes<T> extends AriaAttributes, DOMAttributes<T> {
    'toggleAuthError'?: string;
  }
}
```